# zend route regex issue

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

I am trying to make a route in the ini file to match the following URLs, but I have been unsuccessful.

```
/add-announce.html
/add-announce-books-53.html
```

My route is this:

```
routes.add_announcement.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.add_announcement.route = "/add-announce(-[a-zA-Z_]+)?(-[\d]+)?.html"
routes.add_announcement.defaults.module = announcement
routes.add_announcement.defaults.controller = frontend
routes.add_announcement.defaults.action = add
routes.announcements.defaults.catName = null
routes.announcements.defaults.catId = null
routes.add_announcement.map.catName = 1
routes.add_announcement.map.catId = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because your matches has '-' at the beginning?, Can you try with:

```
routes.add_announcement.route = "add-announce(?:-([a-zA-Z_]+))?(?:-([\d]+))?.html"
```

EDIT: I just found the error, you set the mapped values wrong:

```
routes.add_announcement.map.catName = 1
routes.add_announcement.map.catId = 2
```

instead you have to do it like this:

```
routes.add_announcement.map.1 = "catName"
routes.add_announcement.map.2 = "catId"
```

Also `routes.announcements.defaults.catName` shouldn't be `routes.add_announcement.defaults.catName`?

Comment: Still fails (page won't load). Thank you for your response :)

Comment: @user1059855 I edited my answer.. try to remove the first "/"

Comment: tried removing it, adding backslash. Maybe the issue is somewhere else. Yet all the other normal routes work just fine :-|

Comment: @user1059855 check the new answer.

Comment: my bad when lacking "add_", it shouldn't affect the route anyway. Indeed, swapping the variable mapping made the page load (it seems that the zend manual is outdated as the mapping seems valid in the manual either way). Now to make it work. Cheers :)

Comment: @user1059855, I'm glad I could help, you can mark the answer as correct if you like.